# Java string split numbers

Tags: java, split

I have some rows of numbers in `String str`;
Numbers split by TAB

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
\\... many others, ~ 2 000 strings
```

I need split columns with

1 numbers to massive1,
2 numbers to massive2,
3 numbers to massive3,
4 numbers to massive4,
5 numbers to massive5,
6 numbers to massive6

I know how to solve this task with many `for` / `while` loops but I need compact solve for this task. Maybe I need `Patern.compile` or `String.split`?

Some of my code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= fileLen; i++) {
  while (s.charAt(i) != 13 && s.charAt(i + 1) != 10) {

    while (s.charAt(i) != 9) {
      n1.add((int) s.charAt(i));
      i++;
    }
    // skip TAB
    i++;
    // next for other column
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: what do you mean by 1 numbers to massive1 ?

Comment: for (i=0; i<=fileLen; i++){
 
                while ( s.charAt(i) != 13 && s.charAt(i+1) != 10) { // EOS
 
                    while  (s.charAt(i) != 9) // TAB
                    {
                        n1.add((int)s.charAt(i));
                        i++;
                    }
                    // skip TAB
                    i++;

Comment: Expected output may help to explain what you need.

Comment: @Hades: <code>I need, 1 all column store into massive1: 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . .

Next need, 2 column store into massive2: . 2 . . . . . 2 . . . . . 2 . . . .

Next need, 3 column store into massive3: . . 3 . . . . . 3 . . . . . 3 . . .

Next need, 4 column store into massive4: . . . 4 . . . . . 4 . . . . . 4 . .

Next need, 5 column store into massive5: . . . . 5 . . . . . 5 . . . . . 5 .

Next need, 6 column store into massive6:

. . . . . 6 . . . . . 6 . . . . . 6 . . . . . 6<code>

Comment: Still not clear.

Comment: All formatation is wrong, sorry

Comment: Instead of putting those answers in comments it would be best if you would edit your question and properly format the additional code and output.

Comment: I have Strings str = "1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t\r\n1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t\1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t\"; // many values.  I need collect first number in first string(its 1 number to massive1), next value number 2 to massive2, next value number 3 to massive3, next value number 4 to massive4, next value number 5 to massive5, next value number 6 to massive6, after return to next string and while not end do again and collect 1 number from next string(after return) store at massive1 and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of variables `massive1, ..., massive6` a variable lenght `List massives` would be more suitable:

```
List<List<Integer>> massives = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\R"))  // Stream<String>
    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\t"))                  //   Stream<String>
         .map(field -> Integer::valueOf)                          //   Stream<Integer>
         .collect(Collectors.toList()))                           //   List<Integer>
     .collect(Collectors.toList());                             // List<List<Integer>>

List<int[]> massives = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\R"))
     .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\t"))
         .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
         .toArray())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Maybe with:

```
massive1 = massives.get(0);
massive2 = massives.get(1);
massive3 = massives.get(2);
massive4 = massives.get(3);
...
```

Explanation:

- `String[] String#split(String regex)` would split using the line-break match (`\\R`) into several lines.
- `Stream.of` / `Arrays.stream` turns `String[]` into `Stream<String>` a kind of iteration through every String.
- `Stream.map` turns turns every String when using Integer::valueOf into an Integer.
- `Stream.collect` collects every Integer into a List.

Streams are very expressive, but might not be suited for total beginners, as they combine all into one single expression, which may easily cause errors.

---

***After understanding the question:***

```
int[][] rows = Stream.of(str.split("\\R"))
    .map(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+"))
        .mapToInt(Integer.parseInt)
        .toArray())
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

However one wants the columns:

```
int m = rows.length;
int n = Arrays.stream(rows).mapToInt(line -> line.length).min().orElse(0);

int[][] columns = IntStream.range(0, n)
    .mapToObj(j -> IntStream.range(0, m)
        .map(i -> rows[i][j])
        .toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(columns));
```

Actually I advise to convert rows to columns by classical for-loops;
much better readable.

But a StackOverflow answer should not necessarily pick the easiest way.

Comment: Sorry for delay in answer. I have errors when I'm compile this code: ~~Error:(82, 33) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
      java.lang.Object is not a functional interface)
Error:(84, 29) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>~~

Comment: `field -> Integer::parseInt` should have been either `field -> Integer.parseInt(field)` or the correction in the answer.

Comment: `List<List<Integer>> massives = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\R"))
                    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\t"))
                            .map(field -> Integer.parseInt(field))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());        `                                                                       `// out [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
// I need out [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

Comment: Joop Eggen: Big thanks! its code work for me. I'm master of intelligible explanation(no)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

```
    String str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 \n 1 2 3 4 5 6 \n 1 2 3 4 5 6";
    Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")).stream().map((s) -> s.split(" ")).map((splitBySpace) -> {
        for (String sp : splitBySpace) {
                System.out.print(sp);
            }
            return splitBySpace;
        }).forEachOrdered((String[] _item) -> {
            System.out.println();
    });
```

---Output---
123456
123456
123456

Comment: Must be: mas1 = "111"; mas2="222"; mas="333"; ... mas1 - its first column, mas2=second column; In your example row(without spaces) not column. Sorry for bad explanations.